# How can I Transfer ERC20 tokens from a smart contract without transfer to base account

Tags: go, ethereum, smartcontracts, remix, go-ethereum

I have some ERC20 tokens in a smart contract which created by an account A. I want to transfer ERC20 Token to another address using the gas from A, Without transfer ERC20 Tokens to A . Is there any way to solve my issue

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its "harsh" title.

Answer (score 0):

Just use account A to interact with your erc20 contract. For example, `transfer` or `transferFrom` function might meet your needs.